# The og:image is ignored when the site is shared, although the Facebook Debugger doesn't show any error

Tags: facebook, debugging

I developed a landing in a site with an **addthis tool** to share a dynamic content to Facebook.

For example, in [this page](http://www.dermaglos.com/mes-de-la-mujer-2013/galeria.aspx?id=17440) the dynamic `og content` is as follows:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Pequeña gran heroína – Ingresá a dermaglos.com y participá por importantes premios.">
<meta content="Mi pequeña gran heroína es: Prueba Heroina sin img - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit." property="og:description">
<meta content="http://www.dermaglos.com/DesktopModules/Repository/MakeThumbnail.aspx?tabid=466&amp;mid=1941" property="og:image">
<meta content="http://www.dermaglos.com/Mes-de-la-Mujer-2013/Galeria.aspx?id=17440" property="og:url">
```

When I use a [debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to test the working of the meta information, it doesn't show me errors:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.dermaglos.com%2Fmes-de-la-mujer-2013%2Fgaleria.aspx%3Fid%3D17440

But when a share the page, the FB posting ignores the `og:image` and shows all the images of the `og:url`.

What is happening?

Thanks a lot

Comment: When I click in your link to share, the image is correct...Maybe it's Facebook cache...

Answer (score 0):

Look at this page:

[og:image ignored when sharing link, although accepted in linter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9213912/ogimage-ignored-when-sharing-link-although-accepted-in-linter)

and find in the debugger the following text:

> Tiny og:image:    All the images referenced by og:image should be at least 200px in both dimensions. Please check all the images with tag og:image in the given url and ensure that they meet the minimum specification (Read more on https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/04/03/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/).

Answer (score 0):

While you post image use below property to display image

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="200" />
<meta property="og:image:height" content="200" />
```

Note: Width and height can not be more than 200